# How do I get raw phonetics data with System.Speech in C#?

Tags: c#, phonetics, system.speech.recognition

I would like to know how to get the raw phonetic data from System.Speech in C#.

World or sentence recognition work great, but it's "interpreted" 
to give a coherent and grammatically correct sentence. 
I don't want that; I am looking for a way to get just the translation of audio to phonetics, without interpretation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# return speech phonetic without recognize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063823/c-sharp-return-speech-phonetic-without-recognize-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for here: [Speech to Phoneme in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770593/speech-to-phoneme-in-net)

There is a pronunciation argument for the grammar that can be used with dictation mode:

```
new DictationGrammar("grammar:dictation#pronunciation");
```